# SQL CLR Trigger - get source table

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I am creating a DB synchronization engine using SQL CLR Triggers in Microsoft SQL Server 2012.  These triggers do not call a stored procedure or function (and thereby have access to the INSERTED and DELETED pseudo-tables but do not have access to the @@procid).

Differences [here](http://www.developersite.org/101-166959-sql-server), for reference.

This "sync engine" uses mapping tables to determine what the table and field maps are for this sync job.  In order to determine the target table and fields (from my mapping table) I need to get the source table name from the trigger itself.  I have come across many answers on Stack Overflow and other sites that say that this isn't possible.  But, I've found one [website](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1039228-386-1.aspx) that provides a clue:

**Potential Solution:**

```
using (SqlConnection lConnection = new SqlConnection(@"context connection=true")) {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT object_name(resource_associated_entity_id) FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE request_session_id = @@spid and resource_type = 'OBJECT'", lConnection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    var obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

This does in fact return the correct table name.

**Question:**

My question is, how reliable is this potential solution?  Is the @@spid actually limited to this single trigger execution?  Or is it possible that other simultaneous triggers will overlap within this process id?  Will it stand up to multiple executions of the same and/or different triggers within the database?

From these sites, it *seems* the process Id is in fact limited to the open connection, which doesn't overlap:  [here](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/spid-what-is-it), [here](http://sequelserver.blogspot.com/2013/04/what-is-spid-in-sql-server.html), and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/67a0dac6-62a3-4852-85c0-ebd55aac6bba/sql-server-process-spid-life-cycle?forum=sqldatabaseengine).

Will this be a safe method to get my source table?

**Why?**

As I've noticed similar questions, but all without a valid answer for my specific situation (except that one).  Most of the comments on those sites ask "Why?", and in order to preempt that, here is why:

This synchronization engine operates on a single DB and can push changes to target tables, transforming the data with user-defined transformations, automatic source-to-target type casting and parsing and can even use the CSharpCodeProvider to execute methods also stored in those mapping tables for transforming data.  It is already built, quite robust and has good performance metrics for what we are doing.  I'm now trying to build it out to allow for 1:n table changes (including extension tables requiring the same Id as the 'master' table) and am trying to "genericise" the code.  Previously each trigger had a "target table" definition hard coded in it and I was using my mapping tables to determine the source. Now I'd like to get the source table and use my mapping tables to determine all the target tables.  This is used in a medium-load environment and pushes changes to a "Change Order Book" which a separate server process picks up to finish the CRUD operation.

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments, the query listed above is quite "iffy". It will often (after a SQL Server restart, for example) return system objects like syscolpars or sysidxstats. But, it seems that in the dm_tran_locks table there's always an associated resource_type of 'RID' (Row ID) with the same object_name.  My current query which works reliably so far is the following (will update if this changes or doesn't work under high load testing):

```
select t1.ObjectName FROM (
    SELECT object_name(resource_associated_entity_id) as ObjectName
    FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE resource_type = 'OBJECT' and request_session_id = @@spid
) t1 inner join (
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(partitions.OBJECT_ID) as ObjectName
    FROM sys.dm_tran_locks 
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions ON partitions.hobt_id = dm_tran_locks.resource_associated_entity_id
    WHERE resource_type = 'RID'
) t2 on t1.ObjectName = t2.ObjectName
```

If this is always the case, I'll have to find that out during testing.

Comment: This is iffy. It assumes the engine will take a lock on precisely one object, namely the table your trigger executes on. Maybe that happens to always work out, but you can't really expect anyone to give you guarantees. I'd be less concerned about `@@spid` -- while MARS makes it possible for more than one statement to be active on the connection, this is a kind of fake concurrency. Trigger executions will not overlap, they execute sequentially. You shouldn't have to be concerned about other statements interfering.

Comment: Make sure to test what happens when you throw in transactions, especially when executing under `SERIALIZABLE` (`SELECT * FROM T WITH (HOLDLOCK)`). What happens if the trigger is executed under a transaction where other locks are already held?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to use one trigger (or, perhaps, one set of code) as a trigger for more than one table?

Comment: @BenThul Not exactly.  I still have to create individual triggers, I think, as they need to have the proper SqlTriggerAttribute definitions. I'm still looking into (and learning along the way) how generic I can truly make a trigger. But, they all call a common method.  I'm trying to avoid having to pass in a hard-coded table name when calling that method because I'm not sure how far I can really make it generic and don't want to limit myself later.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're correct that it's iffy. Sometimes (rarely) I see a reference to  syscolpars or sysidxstats when using my query.  But, I think I can join my query up with the sys.partitions and get a dm_trans_lock that has a type of 'RID' with an object name that will match up to the one in my original query.  Still working on it though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How reliable is this potential solution?

While I do not have time to set up a test case to show it not working, I find this approach (even taking into account the query in the **Edit** section) "iffy" (i.e. not *guaranteed* to *always* be reliable).

The main concerns are:

- cascading (whether recursive or not) Trigger executions
- User (i.e. Explicit / Implicit) transactions
- Sub-processes (i.e. `EXEC` and `sp_executesql`)

These scenarios allow for multiple objects to be locked, all at the same time.

> Is the @@SPID actually limited to this single trigger execution? Or is it possible that other simultaneous triggers will overlap within this process id?

and (from a comment on the question):

> I think I can join my query up with the `sys.partitions` and get a `dm_trans_lock` that has a type of 'RID' with an object name that will match up to the one in my original query.

And here is why it shouldn't be entirely reliable: the Session ID (i.e. `@@SPID`) is constant for all of the requests on that Connection). So all sub-processes (i.e. `EXEC` calls, `sp_executesql`, Triggers, etc) will all be on the same `@@SPID` / `session_id`. So, between sub-processes and User Transactions, you can very easily get locks on multiple resources, all on the same Session ID.

The reason I say "resources" instead of "OBJECT" or even "RID" is that locks can occur on: rows, pages, keys, tables, schemas, stored procedures, the database itself, etc. More than one thing can be considered an "OBJECT", and it is possible that you will have page locks instead of row locks.

> Will it stand up to multiple executions of the same and/or different triggers within the database?

As long as these executions occur in different Sessions, then they are a non-issue.

ALL THAT BEING SAID, I can see where simple testing would show that your current method is reliable. However, it should also be easy enough to add more detailed tests that include an explicit transaction that first does some DML on another table, or have a trigger on one table do some DML on one of these tables, etc.

Unfortunately, there is no built-in mechanism that provides the same functionality that `@@PROCID` does for T-SQL Triggers. I have come up with a scheme that *should* allow for getting the parent table for a SQLCLR Trigger (that takes into account these various issues), but haven't had a chance to test it out. It requires using a T-SQL trigger, set as the "first" trigger, to set info that can be discovered by the SQLCLR Trigger.

A simpler form can be constructed using `CONTEXT_INFO`, *if* you are not already using it for something else (and if you don't already have a "first" Trigger set). In this approach you would still create a T-SQL Trigger, and then set it as the "first" Trigger using [sp_settriggerorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-settriggerorder-transact-sql). In this Trigger you [SET CONTEXT_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-context-info-transact-sql) to the table name that is the parent of `@@PROCID`. You can then read [CONTEXT_INFO()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/context-info-transact-sql) on a Context Connection in a SQLCLR Trigger. If there are multiple levels of Triggers then the value of CONTEXT INFO will get overwritten, so reading that value must be the first thing you do in each SQLCLR Trigger.

Comment: I know just enough about SQLCLR to be dangerous, but is there any way to interrogate the SqlTriggerAttribute in the trigger code to tease out the properties of it (in this case, the Target seems relevant)?

Comment: @BenThul In a sense yes. The method attributes are stored in the Assembly and can be discovered via Reflection. However, the "Target" will be a hard-coded value upon compilation. So the value would be the same across all uses of that same `SqlTrigger` method. The only way to get a different value is to recompile and hence have one method per target, which increases the maintenance cost, even if all of the `SqlTrigger` methods call a common method. I will have to test this out to see if it can be put into a more manageable form, and if the `TriggerContext` carries through as expected.

Comment: @srutzky Thanks. Unfortunately I don't see a way to do it other than having single trigger definitions for each table that use a common method. I tried getting info from SqlTriggerAttribute, but that also didn't work for me. How would you suggest I get that? If have to use a different trigger definition for each table individually, I guess it's not too hard to hard-code the table name in the subsequent common method call.  I just didn't want to stop seeing how generic I could truly make it.

Comment: @srutzky I'm marking this as the answer because it gave a detailed explanation on why I can't trust my current method and led me to abandon my attempt and choose a different way (currently simply hard-coding in method call in the trigger definition -- will investigate other options later). Special thanks also to the commenters for adding to my skepticism of my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but it is an FAQ and I think I have a better solution. Essentially it uses the schema of the inserted or deleted table to find the base table by doing a hash of the column names and comparing the hash with the hashes of tables with a CLR trigger on them.

Code snippet below - at some point I will probably put the whole solution on Git (it sends a message to Azure Service Bus when the trigger fires).

```
private const string colqry = "select top 1 * from inserted union all select top 1 * from deleted";
private const string hashqry = "WITH cols as ( "+
                                        "select top 100000 c.object_id, column_id, c.[name] "+
                                        "from sys.columns c "+
                                            "JOIN sys.objects ot on (c.object_id= ot.parent_object_id and ot.type= 'TA') " +
                                        "order by c.object_id, column_id ) "+
                                    "SELECT s.[name] + '.' + o.[name] as 'TableName', CONVERT(NCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5',STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', cols.[name]), 2), '|')),2) as 'MD5Hash' " +
                                    "FROM cols "+
                                        "JOIN sys.objects o on (cols.object_id= o.object_id) "+
                                        "JOIN sys.schemas s on (o.schema_id= s.schema_id) "+
                                    "WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0 "+
                                    "GROUP BY s.[name], o.[name]";

    public static void trgSendSBMsg()
    {
        string table = "";
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader rdr;
        SqlTriggerContext trigContxt = SqlContext.TriggerContext;
        SqlPipe p = SqlContext.Pipe;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string tblhash = "";
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand(colqry, con))
                {
                    using (rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
                    {
                        if (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            MD5 hash = MD5.Create();
                            StringBuilder hashstr = new StringBuilder(250);
                            for (int i=0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                if (i > 0) hashstr.Append("|");
                                hashstr.Append(GetMD5Hash(hash, rdr.GetName(i)));
                            }
                            tblhash = GetMD5Hash(hash, hashstr.ToString().ToUpper()).ToUpper();
                        }
                        rdr.Close();
                    }
                }
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand(hashqry, con))
                {
                    using (rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            string hash = rdr.GetString(1).ToUpper();
                            if (hash == tblhash)
                            {
                                table = rdr.GetString(0);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        rdr.Close();
                    }
                }
                if (table.Length == 0)
                {
                    p.Send("Error: Unable to find table that CLR trigger is on. Message not sent!");
                    return;
                }
….
```

HTH